# Best practice using BIND or ON functions in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-mobile, binding

Recently the jQuery team start recommending to use `on` instead of `bind` for binding events to the DOM.

I would like to know if there is a difference between them, what is the benefit of using the `on` function and if it would be a good call of changing all my `bind`'s to `on`'s functions in my code?

Comment: I'm guessing you meant *"BIND and ON"* in your title and not *"BIND and GO"*, right? the only difference between the two is one will go away eventually.

Comment: `.on` is the standard way to attach event listeners since 1.7 which has been released about [an year and half ago](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/). I wouldn't call that "recently" for a project that has such a fast release cycle as jQuery.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The jQuery project is moving towards putting more and more functionality in fewer methods, instead of having separate methods for every separate thing.

The methods `bind`, `live` and `delegate` have all been replaced by the single method `on`, where you use parameters of different types to determine what the method does.

Comparison:

```
$(sel).bind(event, f);            =    $(sel).on(event, f);
$(sel).live(event, f);            =    $(document.body).on(event, sel, f);
$(sel).delegate(sel2, event, f)   =    $(sel).on(event, sel2, f);
```

If you are using `live`, you should replace that, as the usage of that method is a bit awkward. Also, the `live` method creates a delegate on the body element, and you should try to bind the delegate to a closer scope.

If you are using `bind` and `delegate` it's no panic to replace them with `on` right away. You can do that in new code, and in code that you edit anyway, but those methods are not about to go away in the nearest future.

Answer (score 2):

basically there is no difference in basic use case

```
 $( '#elementID' ).bind( 'click', function(){...} );
 $( '#elementID' ).on( 'click', function(){...} );
```

these two are functionally same..

**`.on()` also does event delegation, and is thus preferred.**

The idea for adding .on() was to create a unified event API, rather than having multiple functions for binding event;

> .on() replaces .bind(), .live() and .delegate().

and as of jquery 1.7 ..`.bind` is just an alias of `.on()`

Answer (score 2):

On attaches an event handler from now and for the future. Bind, however only attaches the event when you set it. If other elements are added dynamically, bind won't fire for those elements.

Comment: The `on` method only creates a delegate if you specify a selector as one of the parameters, otherwise it does the same as `bind`.

Answer (score 1):

`bind` is just a shorthand that will be probably removed. From jQuery's source code:

```
...

bind: function( types, data, fn ) {
    return this.on( types, null, data, fn );
},

...
```

You can look intro the [source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) yourself to find a lot about how jQuery works.

Comment: That's wrong. `.on()` manage event delegation, `bind` doesn't

Comment: K, update it to be more precise

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `bind` bind an event, `on` can bind event too, but it can also manage event delegation.

http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

If you want to check this more in detail, checkout this blog post: http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html